# function ST_Line_Interpolate_Point with multilinestring

Tags: postgis

Is there a function like ST_Line_Interpolate_Point but using a multilinestring?

Comment: You mean a linestring wrapped in a multilinestring or a true multiline.  What does a percentage mean when a multilinestring is not connected?  If you have connected multlinestrings then you can use ST_LineMerge to merge into one linestring

Comment: I mean in a multiline that is conected, and I want to search a random percentage in the multiline.

Comment: What if the multilines are connected in a Y-shape? Short answer: no, there isn't one for multilinestring, because the semantics of it make limited sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it, just have to use first of all the function `st_linemerge`, then use the function `st_makeline` and finally use `ST_line_interpolate_point`.

```
ST_line_interpolate_point(st_makeline(st_linemerge(geom)),fraction);
```

Comment: Note that `ST_LineMerge` will only merge the lines in a multi-linestring if end and start point of two consecutive lines are at the same position. See also the examples in the documentation: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineMerge.html